# Converting integer to text during the select query in MySQL

Tags: mysql

I'm trying to select an integer field as text but I have no idea how to do it.

The `1` represents `low`, the `2` represents `medium`, and `3` represents `hi`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT CASE intfield
        WHEN 1 THEN 'low'
        WHEN 2 THEN 'medium'
        WHEN 3 THEN 'hi'       
    END AS inttext
FROM table
```

Answer (score 3):

you can do this with `CASE WHEN`

```
SELECT (CASE WHEN column = 1 THEN "low"
             WHEN column = 2 THEN "medium"
             WHEN column = 3 THEN "high"
        END) AS value
FROM table_name;
```

Answer (score 2):

```
Select 
CASE WHEN field = 1 then 'low' 
WHEN field = 2 then 'medium'
WHEN field = 3 then 'hi'
END as Col
from yourtable;
```